# mount a disk as /mydisk and show it in file browser as devices

Tags: 13.10, fstab

My machine has 2 disk.
the second disk mounts ok in the file browser in the device section but its mount path is in /media/machine/mydisk which is a pain when one want to acces files within mydisk using command line. 
To solve this I added an entry in fstab with a short path (/data/ leads to my disk).

```
/dev/sda1    /data   ext4  rw,auto   0  2
```

Problem is, after i did this, my disk doesn't appear anymore in my file browser (which is handy in mouse mode), and the only way to access it is through /data/

Question is : how can I have my disk mounted in /data/ and apear in ubuntu file browser as a disk in the device section ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to bookmark this location. It will be accessible the same way, just placed in `Bookmarks` instead of `Device` section.

There is also easy way to put it in `Places` section if you would like to. Just edit `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it does the job. I didn't manage to add a new folder in Places using user_dirs.dirs but I created bookmarks with Ctrl-D (any way of changing the icon ?)

Comment: Sure. Afraid I can't help you with the icon.